# Identify 5 pin SMD component marked 'VTU'

Tags: integrated-circuit, identification

This 5 pin SMD component is placed on Growatt 5KW control card (solar inverter). Marking code is VTU. What type of component this is?

[image: 5 pin SMD component]

Comment: Show us context. What's around it?  What's on the back side of the board?  What is it connected to?

Answer (score 2):

It's a onsemi [M74VHC1GT08DTT1G](https://datasheet.lcsc.com/lcsc/1809111715_onsemi-M74VHC1GT08DFT2G_C99673.pdf) AND gate.

[image]

[image]

(Source: [lcsc.com](https://www.lcsc.com/product-detail/Gates_onsemi-M74VHC1GT08DTT1G_C233441.html))